# Gradle searching at wrong URL for 'io.nano:android-tex:1.0.0'

Tags: android, gradle, latex

I cannot start my Android App if it includes the following line in the dependencies of the module level build.gradle file:

```
dependencies{
    ... 
    implementation 'io.nano:android-tex:1.0.0' 
    ... 
}
```

The gradle sync works without errors.

But when I try to start the app, I get the error that io.nano:android-tex:1.0.0 cannot be found. Here is a part of the error log:

```
3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find io.nano:android-tex:1.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/nano/android-tex/1.0.0/android-tex-1.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/nano/android-tex/1.0.0/android-tex-1.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

It seems to me that the URLs are simply wrong. https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/nano/android-tex/1.0.0/android-tex-1.0.0.pom does not lead to anywhere useful.

But the library exists on maven (see here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.nano/android-tex/1.0.0).

Is my gradle not smart enough to search at the right place?

A couple of months ago, I successfully used 'io.nano:android-tex:1.0.0' in a project. But after updating Android Studio to Bumblebee and updating gradle from 7.0.2 to 7.2, it does not work anymore. (I don't know if those upgrades are the reason, though, because it has been months since I had worked on the project the last time).

Can anyone help with this? I just want to find a way to use 'io.nano:android-tex:1.0.0' again in an Android App.

--- EDIT ---

I have also added jcenter to my repositories in my project level gradle file (to check if that makes a difference):

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
```

Unfortunately, that does not help.

Answer (score 0):

from [github site](https://github.com/NanoMichael/AndroidLaTeXMath):

> Library is available in jcenter repository, add this script to your build.gradle file to install:

you should add `jcenter()` to your libs repository, but remember that jcenter is kind-of [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration). ask lib author for moving to more reliable repository

Comment: I added jcenter(). It does not make a difference. The error message stays the same.

Comment: ensure you've posted this line in [proper gradle file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772252/using-jcenter-with-gradle-in-android-studio)

Comment: Yes, I have put it in the project level gradle (see the edit of my question). Unfortunately, it does not make a difference with the issue.